# Invoking restful Soap web service in android

Tags: android, web-services, restful-url, saprfc

I am trying to invoke the `SOAP Web Service` in android in `Restful` methodology.

```
DefaultHttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpHost targetHost=new HttpHost("87.11.9.26", 8000, "http");
client.getCredentialsProvider()  
.setCredentials(new AuthScope(targetHost.getHostName(),  
                targetHost.getPort()),  
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials("abcdefg","*******"));
BasicScheme basicAuth=new BasicScheme();
BasicHttpContext localcontex=new BasicHttpContext();
localcontex.setAttribute(ClientContext.AUTH_SCHEME_PREF, basicAuth);
HttpGet request=new HttpGet("http://87.11.9.26:8000/sap/bc/srt/rfc/  
sap/zmaterials_group_list/800/zmaterials_group_list/zmaterials_group_list_bind/");

ResponseHandler<String> handler=new BasicResponseHandler();
try {
     System.out.println("**********target host is****************"+targetHost);
     System.out.println("**********request is****************"+request);
     result=client.execute(targetHost, request, handler);
     System.out.println("**************************"+result);
     // client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

then it gives the exception as

```
org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: SRT: Unexpected failure in SOAP  
processing occurred: ("No Web service configuration for this  
 access path: "/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/zmaterials_group_list/800/zmat"")
```

Please help me where I did wrong.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOAP and REST are quite different principles. `/sap/bc/srt/rfc` is the prefix of the SOAP runtime for RFC, and it requires you to provide correctly formatted SOAP requesty, obeying to the WSDL / schema and so on. I may be wrong, but I doubt you'll be able to provide RESTful services using this adapter. You (or whoever wrote that function module `zmaterials_group_list`) will have to implement your own ICF HTTP handler if you want to go for RESTful services.

That being said, check the service path in the configuration (`SICF`) and make sure that the service you're trying to call is present and enabled. Also check whether the [WS runtime](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70ehp2/helpdata/en/46/abbc05ba0c2a7fe10000000a1553f6/frameset.htm) is configured correctly.